# How do I express the idea that at a buffet some food is being taken by people at a quick rate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Image I'm at a buffet and some kind of food is really popular so that the food is being taken by lots of people and soon they will be gone.

So should I express the idea that some food are being consumed quickly?

I was trying to use `run out of` but I realized the subject of `run out of` seems like it can only be people, or the owner. What if I want the subject to be the food?

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with saying that you are about to (or have) run out of food.

Comment: @JasonBassford but saying that sounds like I own the food but apparently I do not and I am just a customer

Comment: You can simply say *the food is about to run out*. That doesn't imply anything at all about ownership.

Comment: @JasonBassford then what if I was referring to the fact that the food was going fast at the buffet later after the dinner. Should I say "The food was running out quickly/fast"?

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, you can just say:

> The food is going fast.

And when it has all been consumed/taken:

> The food is gone.

Comment: thanks for replying! under what circumstance should I say `foods` instead of `food`?

Comment: @ZhenghaoHe The plural **foods** is used to emphasize the variety of food. For example, you would say _frozen foods_.